# Does Eighth Seal's save against domination function across multiple turns?

Tags: dnd-4e

[Eighth Seal](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/epicdestiny.aspx?id=764) has a level 24 ability:

> The Mind's Shining Corridors (24th level): ...
>
> In addition, when you are subjected to an effect that dazes, dominates, or stuns you that a save can end, you can make a saving throw against that effect a the start of your next turn. If you save, the effect ends on you.

If the first start of turn save is failed, can the eighth seal save again at the start of her next turn?

Comment: I'd probably argue that no, it doesn't since the triggering condition is "when you are subjected". But I don't know enough about 4e to commit to that.

Comment: What does 'first start of turn save' mean? Don't you normally save at the end of your turn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems to come down to do we interpret "when you are subjected to..." as meaning "while you are subjected to" or "when you become subjected to"

Typically I've been reading "when you are..." as "when you become..."

So, **No**, the save at the beginning of your turn happens only on the first start of your next turn.